# How to check if fields values between objects (stored within an associative array) are equal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, lodash

Let say I have [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gv4kk20m/) code:

```
var denti={}

function Dente() {
    this.ID = "";
    this.Tipologia = "";
    this.Lavorazione = "";
}

var dente = new Dente();
dente.ID="id1";
dente.Tipologia="tipo1";
dente.Lavorazione="lavoro1";
denti[dente.ID] = dente;

dente = new Dente();
dente.ID="id2";
dente.Tipologia="tipo1";
dente.Lavorazione="lavoro2";
denti[dente.ID] = dente;

dente = new Dente();
dente.ID="id3";
dente.Tipologia="tipo1";
dente.Lavorazione="lavoro1";
denti[dente.ID] = dente;
```

I need to check if all field `Tipologia` and `Lavorazione` are the same.

In this case, the function I ask `CheckArrayTipologia()` should return `true` (all `.Tipologia` fields values are the same, `tipo1`).

Instead, `CheckArrayLavorazione()` should return `false` (they are not all `lavoro1`, there is a `lavoro2`).

How would you do this fast in Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: You didn't post `CheckArrayTipologia()` so who can say how to make it "faster"?

Comment: `CheckArrayTipologia()` is the function I'm asking to you :)

Comment: *How would you do this faster* - faster than what? There's no code. *edit* ah.

Comment: sorry, typo! I meant fast.

Comment: You are always overwrite the same object `dente`

Comment: @isvforall I thought that too, but there are those calls to `new Dente()` so I think it's OK.

Comment: All you can do is iterate through all the objects and check the properties. I'd do it with `Object.keys()` and the `.every()` method on the Array prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solves your issue:

```
function CheckArrayTipologia() {
    var tipologia;

    for (dente in denti) {
        if (!tipologia) {
            tipologia = dente.Tipologia;
            continue;
        }

        if (tipologia !== dente.Tipologia) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gv4kk20m/4)**</kbd>

Or with **Lodash**, shorter:

```
function CheckArrayTipologia() {
    var values = _.values(denti);
    return _.every(values, 'Tipologia', _.first(values).Tipologia);
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gv4kk20m/3)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

First I'd recommend using an array to store your objects - if you need to get an object from its id you can use `filter`.

```
var denti = [];
```

I've rewritten your constructor so that you pass in a param object instead and set its properties to be the new object properties:

```
function Dente(params) {
  for (var p in params) {
    this[p] = params[p];
  }
}
```

Now just define a new object and immediately push it to the array:

```
denti.push(new Dente({
  id: 'id1',
  Tipologia: 'tipo1',
  Lavorazione: 'lavoro1'
}));
```

Then you can write a generic function into which you pass your array and the property of the objects you want to check:

```
function checkSame(arr, prop) {
  if (!arr.length) return false;

  // extract the property values from each object
  return arr.map(function (el) {
    return el[prop];

  // Check if they're all the same
  }).every(function (el, i, arr) {
    return el === arr[0];
  });
}

checkSame(denti, 'Tipologia'); // true
checkSame(denti, 'Lavorazione'); // false
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qsq09aqm/2/)

Or slightly more functional JS (ES6):

```
const pick = (prop) => obj => obj[prop];
const same = (el, i, arr) => el === arr[0];
const checkSame = (arr, prop) => arr.map(pick(prop)).every(same);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2fm7g70j/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check with [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function

```
var patternID = 'id1';

var res = Object.keys(denti).every(id => 
    denti[id].Lavorazione == denti[patternID].Lavorazione &&
    denti[id].Tipologia == denti[patternID].Lavorazione);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using Underscore.js then you can do it like this:

```
var tipologias = _.map(denti, function(d) { 
    return d.Tipologia; 
});
var areAllTipologiasEqual = _.uniq(tipologias).length === 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit alteration to @GG solution, to make it more faster

```
function CheckArrayTipologia() {
    var lastTipologia;

    for (dente in denti) {
        if (!lastTipologia) {
            lastTipologia = dente.Tipologia;
            continue;
        }

        if (lastTipologia !== dente.Tipologia) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```